# Caffe Error - Data Transformer Check Failed: datum_channels > 0 (0 vs. 0)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

If anyone knows what each of the three numbers in this error message means exactly, then I'd definitely appreciate a description, so I can avoid an audit of the data_transformer.cpp code.

Yes, I understand the broad brushstrokes of the error.. a mismatch between the LMDB entries and the Caffe data layer reading the entries.  But in order to fix the error, I need to understand what the first zero in the error message means.  And the second zero, and the third.

**Context**

- Caffe data layer is reading from an LMDB source
- LMDB entries contain custom, non-image data comprising (c x h x w) 1 x 1024 x 300 float values

> ```
> I0816 20:28:34.749409 103 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer data
> I0816 20:28:34.768201 103 db_lmdb.cpp:35] Opened lmdb ../data/emails/inbox
> I0816 20:28:34.768442 103 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer data
> I0816 20:28:34.768995 103 net.cpp:380] data -> data
> I0816 20:28:34.769502 103 net.cpp:380] data -> label
> F0816 20:28:34.770326 103 data_transformer.cpp:465] Check failed: datum_channels > 0 (0 vs. 0)
> ```

**UPDATE**

I resorted to a byte-level scrub of the LMDB records being read by Caffe to understand the reason for this error.  Below is a sample record:

Key = string value of "00000000_"

Record comprises serialized header and data in row-major form. For ease, all values are in decimal form:

Header

1. Byte 0 =  8   Byte 1 =   1                (field 1 of type int32 = 1)
2. Byte 2 = 16   Byte 3 = 128   Byte 4 =   8 (field 2 of type int32 = 1024)
3. Byte 5 = 24   Byte 6 = 172   Byte 7 =   2 (field 3 of type int32 = 300)
4. Byte 8 = 40   Byte 9 =   0                (field 5 of type int32 = 0)
5. Byte 10 = 56  Byte 11 =  0                (field 7 of type boolean = 0)

Data (first three float values among the 300 in the first row)

6. Byte 12 = 53   Byte 13 =  64   Byte 14 = 164   Byte 15 =  95   Byte 16 = 190
7. Byte 17 = 53   Byte 18 = 176   Byte 19 = 254   Byte 20 = 143   Byte 21 = 190
8. Byte 22 = 53   Byte 23 =  24   Byte 24 =  96   Byte 25 = 191   Byte 26 =  62

Field = 53 signifies a fixed length, 32-bit float value in the ensuing four bytes.  These values are non-VarInt and in (or should be in) little endian form.

Unless I'm overlooking something completely fundamental, why would Caffe be seeing zero channels in this data stream?

Answer (score 0):

[This line](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp#L465) in `data_transformer.cpp` raises your error:

> ```
> CHECK_GT(datum_channels, 0);
> ```

Caffe checks that the `Datum` read from LMDB is valid. The check that fails you is verifying `datum_channels` is strictly greater than zero.
Your error implies you have an "empty" Datum: an entry with zero channels.

I suggest you go through your lmdb and verify all entries are valid.

Comment: Shai - Please take a look at the byte-level data I appended in the original post.  Any ideas on why Caffe would be seeing zero channels?

Comment: @PeteJanda you need to use caffe's protobuf to "parse" the binary data stored in the lmdb. See for example [this blog](https://research.beenfrog.com/code/2015/12/30/write-read-lmdb-example.html) on how to do it in python. Once you get a `datum` element from the dataset, you can check how many channels it got. Moreover, you might have all but one of your entries in the datebase with channel=1, it is enough for one corrupt entry to raise that error when you hit it.

Comment: I eliminated the possibility of a corrupt LMDB record by whittling the database down to a single entry, which I scrubbed byte for byte for validity.  The error persists, and I'm left scratching my head about your comment:  "You need to use Caffe's protobuf to 'parse' the binary data stored in LMDB."  The sole LMDB record contains a (correct) encoding of the Datum class defined in caffe.proto and my float data.  Does Caffe's data layer with an LMDB backend require some sort of pre-processing to accept such LMDB entries?  My understanding is that no pre-processing is needed.

Comment: Shai - I just examined DataLayer::DataLayerSetup and noticed the top blob getting initialized with "datum.ParseFromString(cursor_->value() );"  Is my fundamental misunderstanding that LMDB records need to be ASCII strings describing Datum and its contents rather than the binary encoding of the Datum class and its contents???  If yes, can you point me to any documentation that describes how the ASCII string should look?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LMDB environments cannot have more than one database, else Caffe will not know what to do, attempt to read the first DB's information and throw an error along the lines mentioned above when the information is not in the expected `caffe.proto` format.

Because of legacy reasons, my LMDB environment was set up to have *named* databases, which meant that a separate database containing database names was also present.  So even though one DB with data of interest resided in the specified file path, there were actually two DBs.  Caffe was reading the first, non-Caffe data DB.

Bottom Line: no named LMDB databases!